# Database 'height_collector' does not exist! Python flask

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

When i  am trying to connect to my existing database(it is realy exist) i have an ERROR occur:
Here is my code and error:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:postgres510@localhost/height_collector'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Data(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "data"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_ = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    height_ = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, email_, height_):
        self.email_ = email_
        self.heigth_ = height_


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/success", methods=['post'])
def success():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form["email_name"]
        height = request.form["height_name"]
        print(email, height)
        return render_template("success.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

and then i have an error
[Data base ".." doesn't exist!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCHde.png)
Here is a picture of my database 
[image]

Comment: i don't know how it works on windows, but i think any way, it will be good solution to create special database user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be sure, but this is probably related to either network names, postgres server config, or permissions.

You need to go through different possibilities step by step and eliminate them as the cause. You can connect and see the db in pgAdmin, and you can't connect in Flask. Somewhere between these two is a difference which stops it from working.

1. Double-check that in pgAdmin you can correctly open the database which you see pictured and look at the tables (if any). It could be that pgAdmin is showing this db open but it isn't connectable any more.
2. Can you make sure that in pgAdmin, you use `localhost` as the host name of your connection, and not the IP address of the machine or anything else. If this is the problem, you need to look at how postgres is configured, and in particular the `listen` key in the postgres config. If `listen` is set to `localhost`, you should be good.
3. I don't see where you mentioned that you are using Windows, but another answerer seems to have assumed this, is this the case? Does the command `ping localhost` in a shell succeed?
4. Connect in pgAdmin using the exact user and password that you use in your Flask code.
5. Try to connect in Python, not in Flask. Open a Python shell, import `psycopg2` and call `psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', user='postgres', ...)`